# In PHP How to display a users information once they have correctly logged in

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have searched an tried many examples and solutions and come to the same problem and would be grateful if someone could help.

Essentially I have the database connected and when they log in correctly the page is directed to the `login_success.php`. Once taken to the page I want the user to be shown their details.

I obviously don't expect the answer I'm just hoping to understand where I'm going wrong.

```
<?php
        ob_start();
        include 'connect.php';
    } else {
        header('Location: main_login.php?error=2');
    }
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. They are deprecated

Comment: What is the problem? What does not succeed?

Comment: The above code is terribly unsafe. Please sanitize your inputs. Parametrized queries wouldn't hurt either. Use mysqli or PDO methods instead.

Comment: Dont't use MD5 hash, too easy to find collisions.

Comment: Also, `$result =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address = '$myusername'";` should be `$result = mysql_query(...);` But it'd be better not to use mysql_* at all.

Comment: This code is very broken on several accounts :| Surely there must a *good* and/or authoritative PHP project on securer-ly implementing authentication?

Comment: `session_start()` must be called before setting `$_SESSION['whatever']`. Also, you should be using mysqli. If you want to save keystrokes, the object oriented methodology is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not starting your session in the login file.  This would cause your `$_SESSION` variables to not carry over to the next page after they log in.  Since you are requiring `connect.php` in all of your files (more than likely), you should put `session_start()` at the top of that.  That way your session is started and you don't have to type that one line in every code page.

You are echoing out information in `login_success.php` before the `html` tag.  Instead, go into your code where you want it displayed and use:

```
<?= "your email is... ".$_SESSION['myusername']; ?>
<?= $row['forename'] . " " . $row['surname']; ?>
```

If you do not see anything for any of the `$row` variables, try printing `$row` to the screen to check them period.

```
<? print_r($row); ?>
```

If you do not see anything for `$row`, your query isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I have made the changes along with @bongsky and will update the code. I seem to be churning out the error Undefined index: myusername. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3068091 This may be referring to the `$_POST` array and not the `$_SESSION` array.  Are you submitting a form?  Honestly, I'm surprised you're getting that error at all.  Usually you only get an error like that if you are trying to access an array from it's index #.  What line does this error say it occurs on?  (What's the code for the line?)

Comment: I'm submitting the login form and when successful the errors show. They are in the lines 6,8 and 16 which is where the $_POSTS are.

Comment: Ok, then at the top of the page, do `print_r($_POST);` to see if anything is coming over.  In your login form, do you have the action set to `post` or `get`, or are you setting the action at all?

Comment: Nothing came through. Also I'm using action set as post.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the username and password first before assigning it on a session, like this:

```
$login_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email_address = '".$myusername."' and password = '".$mypassword."'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($login_user);



$_SESSION['myusername'] = $row['myusername'];
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $row['password'];
```

And don't use mysql functions anymore, they're no longer supported and maintained, and are officially depreciated.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my post but am still suffering from  Undefined index: myusername. I understand this could be because the mysql functions are outdated, so I will begin learning for an alternative to this i suppose as we are running php 5.3.3

Comment: yes... mysql functions are no longer updated... try mysqli or PDO,